# ECC memory overflow on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make some eliptic cureve crypto code work on Android. (https://github.com/k3d3/ed25519-java). It works fine on the computer but on Android I get a StackOverflowError.

Where the problem occurs depends on the Android device. On one it's in scalarmult() on another expmod(). The debugger shows it to work for a while then sudden death. Any ideas? Memory problem?

```
    static BigInteger[] scalarmult(BigInteger[] P, BigInteger e) {
    //System.out.println("scalarmult open with e = " + e);
    if (e.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        System.out.println("scalarmult close with Q = 0,1");
        return new BigInteger[]{BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE};
    }
    BigInteger[] Q = scalarmult(P, e.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)));
    //System.out.println("scalarmult asQ = " + Q[0] + "," + Q[1]);
    Q = edwards(Q, Q);
    //System.out.println("scalarmult aeQ = " + Q[0] + "," + Q[1] + " e="+e+" testbit="+(e.testBit(0)?1:0));
    if (e.testBit(0)) Q = edwards(Q, P);
    //System.out.println("scalarmult close with Q = " + Q[0] + "," + Q[1]);
    return Q;
}


static BigInteger expmod(BigInteger b, BigInteger e, BigInteger m) {
    //System.out.println("expmod open with b=" + b + " e=" + e + " m=" + m);
    if (e.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        //System.out.println("expmod close with 1z");
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    BigInteger t = expmod(b, e.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)), m).pow(2).mod(m);
    //System.out.println("expmod 1/2 t="+t+" e="+e+" testbit="+(e.testBit(0)?1:0));
    if (e.testBit(0)) {
        t = t.multiply(b).mod(m);
    }
    //System.out.println("expmod close with " + t);
    return t;
}
```

Stack trace (cut of the last part since it's just repeating it self):

```
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749): java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.<init>(FinalizerReference.java:34)
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:48)
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at java.math.BigInt.<init>(BigInt.java:24)
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at java.math.BigInteger.divide(BigInteger.java:903)
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.test.crypto.Curve25519.expmod(Curve25519.java:45)
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.test.crypto.Curve25519.expmod(Curve25519.java:45)
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.test.crypto.Curve25519.expmod(Curve25519.java:45)
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.test.crypto.Curve25519.expmod(Curve25519.java:45)
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.test.crypto.Curve25519.expmod(Curve25519.java:45)
10-06 19:00:17.855: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.test.crypto.Curve25519.expmod(Curve25519.java:45)
```

Comment: Provide Stacktrace from logcat please.

Comment: Your expmod method when called recursively will only ever jump out if `e equals zero` Looks like it doesn't so you get a stackoverflow

Comment: But then it should not have worked on the computer??

Comment: It depends on environment, I guess you used standard Java with a JVM on your computer. When you run those code on your Android device, you're running your code on a Dalvik VM, which has different configurations --> different stack size limit (might be smaller than the one on your computer). Since those methods are not so complicated, you can convert them to using loop instead, that will solve your problem.